# Bootstrap modal is not popping up on chrome though working well on microsoft edge

Tags: django, modal-dialog

i have used a bootstrap modal in my project .All is working well except modal. when i was using microsoft edge modal is popping up with good manner but something wrong with the google chrome.

now how can i get the modal pop up on chrome with best user experience

Though it is working while i removed "fade" from the class, it popped up with a dark background, i think this is not a good user experience

Answer (score 0):

Do hard refresh it might help you. A hard refresh clears your browser cache for a specific page, which forces it to load the most recent version of that page. This could include new scripts, styles or features.

```
Ctrl+F5
```

[This](https://www.documate.org/resources/what-is-a-hard-refresh-how-to-do-a-hard-refresh-in-any-browser) is the link for different commands for different browsers.